# Using system calls from C, how do I get the utilization of the CPU(s)?

Tags: c, freebsd

In C on FreeBSD, how does one access the CPU utilization?

I am writing some code to handle HTTP redirects. If the CPU load goes above a threshold on a FReeBSD system, I want to redirect client requests. Looking over the man pages, kvm_getpcpu() seems to be the right answer, but the man pages (that I read) don't document the usage.

Any tips or pointers would be welcome - thanks!

---

After reading the answers here, I was able to come up with the below. Due to the poor documentation, I'm not 100% sure it is correct, but top seems to agree. Thanks to everyone who answered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CP_USER   0
#define CP_NICE   1
#define CP_SYS    2
#define CP_INTR   3
#define CP_IDLE   4
#define CPUSTATES 5

int main()
{
        long cur[CPUSTATES], last[CPUSTATES];
        size_t cur_sz = sizeof cur;
        int state, i;
        long sum;
        double util;

        memset(last, 0, sizeof last);

        for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
                if (sysctlbyname("kern.cp_time", &cur, &cur_sz, NULL, 0) < 0)
                {
                        printf ("Error reading kern.cp_times sysctl\n");
                        return -1;
                }

                sum = 0;
                for (state = 0; state<CPUSTATES; state++)
                {
                        long tmp = cur[state];
                        cur[state] -= last[state];
                        last[state] = tmp;
                        sum += cur[state];
                }

                util = 100.0L - (100.0L * cur[CP_IDLE] / (sum ? (double) sum : 1.0L));
                printf("cpu utilization: %7.3f\n", util);
                sleep(1);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MAN pages

**NAME**

kvm_getmaxcpu, kvm_getpcpu -- access per-CPU data

**LIBRARY**

Kernel Data Access Library (libkvm, -lkvm)

**SYNOPSIS**

```
 #include <sys/param.h>
 #include <sys/pcpu.h>
 #include <sys/sysctl.h>
 #include <kvm.h>

 int
 kvm_getmaxcpu(kvm_t *kd);

 void *
 kvm_getpcpu(kvm_t *kd, int cpu);
```

**DESCRIPTION**

The kvm_getmaxcpu() and kvm_getpcpu() functions are used to access the
per-CPU data of active processors in the kernel indicated by kd.  The
kvm_getmaxcpu() function returns the maximum number of CPUs supported by
the kernel.  The kvm_getpcpu() function returns a buffer holding the per-
CPU data for a single CPU.  This buffer is described by the struct pcpu
type.  The caller is responsible for releasing the buffer via a call to
free(3) when it is no longer needed.  If cpu is not active, then NULL is
returned instead.

**CACHING**

These functions cache the nlist values for various kernel variables which
are reused in successive calls.  You may call either function with kd set
to NULL to clear this cache.

**RETURN VALUES**

On success, the kvm_getmaxcpu() function returns the maximum number of
CPUs supported by the kernel.  If an error occurs, it returns -1 instead.

On success, the kvm_getpcpu() function returns a pointer to an allocated
buffer or NULL. If an error occurs, it returns -1 instead.

If either function encounters an error, then an error message may be
retrieved via kvm_geterr(3.)

---

**EDIT**

Here's the kvm_t struct:

```
struct __kvm {
    /*
     * a string to be prepended to error messages
     * provided for compatibility with sun's interface
     * if this value is null, errors are saved in errbuf[]
     */
    const char *program;
    char   *errp;           /* XXX this can probably go away */
    char    errbuf[_POSIX2_LINE_MAX];
    #define ISALIVE(kd) ((kd)->vmfd >= 0)
    int     pmfd;           /* physical memory file (or crashdump) */
    int     vmfd;           /* virtual memory file (-1 if crashdump) */
    int     unused;         /* was: swap file (e.g., /dev/drum) */
    int     nlfd;           /* namelist file (e.g., /kernel) */
    struct kinfo_proc *procbase;
    char   *argspc;         /* (dynamic) storage for argv strings */
    int     arglen;         /* length of the above */
    char    **argv;         /* (dynamic) storage for argv pointers */
    int     argc;           /* length of above (not actual # present) */
    char    *argbuf;        /* (dynamic) temporary storage */
    /*
     * Kernel virtual address translation state.  This only gets filled
     * in for dead kernels; otherwise, the running kernel (i.e. kmem)
     * will do the translations for us.  It could be big, so we
     * only allocate it if necessary.
     */
    struct vmstate *vmst;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to look into 'man sysctl'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact library, command, or system call; however, if you really get stuck, download the source code to top.  It displays per-cpu stats when you use the "-P" flag, and it has to get that information from somewhere.